Young adult book set in a post-nuclear wasteland (but is actually a video game/computer simulation?)
I read a book when I was in elementary school (circa 1995) that to my recollection was about a child/pre-teen who is living in a post-apocalyptic wasteland (maybe it's a girl searching for her brother?), but then we find out at the end that it was all just some sort of simulation or video game.
For a long time I thought the book I was remembering was Z for Zachariah, but having read that recently I discovered it's not, so now I'm at a total loss.
I have an image in my mind of the book being somewhat thick and the size of a paperback, but with a hardcover, like how they used to make books that you would find in school libraries.
Would love to hear anyone's thoughts on what this title could be!

How do they discover that it's a simulation?  What is the "real world" like?

@DavidW I don't recall unfortunately. In my memory, the whole book is set in the game/simulation environment and it's not until the very end that you find out it's not the real world. I can't remember what the "real world" was like, though.
